# Sencha nested json display in Dataview

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

Please help me to solve this issue.. am spending too much time to sort it out..
I have a json file i want to display it in dataview.. i can display the parent values but cannot getting the child nodes

this is my json format

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Science Gallery",

            "menu": [
                {
                    "commenttext": "SC Sandwich"
                },
                {
                    "commenttext": "SC Toasted Sandwich"
                },
                {
                    "commenttext": "SC Panini"
                },
                {
                    "commenttext": "SC Ciabatta"
                },
                {
                    "commenttext": "SC Burrito"
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

This is my View 
/**
 * TouchCalendar.view.EventListPanel
 */

```
Ext.define('WinReo.view.PropertyDetailsView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    requires: [
        'Ext.dataview.List',
        'Ext.layout.Fit'
    ],

    alias: 'widget.propertydetailsview',
    id:'propertydetailsview',
    config: {
        // title   : 'Events List',
        layout  : 'fit',
        store:'WinReo.store.PropertyDetails',
        id:'propertydetailsview',
        cls:'propertydetailscss',


    },

    initialize: function(){


       var listadd =  Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {
            fullscreen: true,
            id: 'ListePieces',
           //itemTpl:  listTemplate,
           //data:[],
           itemTpl: [
               '{name}',
               '<div>',
               '<h2><b>Menu</b></h2>',
               '<tpl for="menu">',
               '<div>{item}</div>',
               '</tpl>',
               '</div>'
           ].join(''),

           loadingText: 'Loading...',
           store: storedetails
           /*listeners:{
               itemtap: function(record, index){

                alert('hi');
               }
           }*/

        });
        this.add(listadd);


    }

});
```

Here is my model

```
Ext.define('WinReo.model.PropertyDetailsModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   // requires: ['WinReo.model.PropertyDetailsModelComments'],
    config: {
        fields: [

            {name: 'name'},
            {name: 'commenttext'},
            {name: 'item'}


        ]
    }


});
```

Here is my Store

```
Ext.define('WinReo.store.PropertyDetails', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'WinReo.model.PropertyDetailsModel',

        'Ext.data.Store',
        'Ext.dataview.DataView',
        'Ext.data.NodeStore',
        'Ext.data.TreeStore'
    ],

    config: {
        storeId: 'propertydetails',
        defaultRootProperty: 'items',
        model: 'WinReo.model.PropertyDetailsModel',
        autoLoad: true,


        proxy: {

            type: 'ajax',
            method:'post',
            url: 'resources/data/fullproperty.json',
            //url: apiurl+'PropertyList.ashx?switch=GetPIP&reoid=',

            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'items'

            }
        }


    }

});
```

Can i display this nested json with noram Model, is there any model association is needed?

please help...ur help is much appreciated..thanks in advance

Comment: Do not post a question a second if you think you waited to long for an answer. Much better is to edit the existing one to get (better) response

Comment: sorry i will delete my earlier post..i was too complicated i think ..

Answer (score 0):

Change your proxy setting in your store as follows. I removed 'rootProperty' and add 'record'

```
proxy: {
type: 'ajax',
method:'post',
url: 'resources/data/fullproperty.json',
//url: apiurl+'PropertyList.ashx?switch=GetPIP&reoid=',
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    record: 'items'
}
```

}